# How to automatically map URL to Request Handler in webapp2?

Tags: python, web-applications, web.py, webapp2

I'm trying to find a way to automatically map URL to Request Handler in webapp2.

Here's what I want to get: with the classes below, all request to `/users` can be handled by `Users`, and all requests to `/lists` can be handled by `Lists`, without hardcode `(URLRegex, RequestHandler)` tuples in `webapp2.WSGIApplication`

```
class Users(webapp2.RequestHandler):  
    pass
class Lists(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    pass
```

It's very easy in `webpy` using `auto_application`. In `webpy` it uses `metaclass` to automatically register the new class to a global URL dispacher.

Since I'm not very familiar to `metaclass`, I'm wondering if there's already such method/example code available in `webapp2`?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is have all URLs handled by a single dispatcher handler using a wildcard pattern. E.g. "/(.*)" will be handled by the dispatcher. The dispatcher can analyse the url, instantiate the appropriate class and invoke whatever method on it.

However, there maye be some security issues, as the browser will be able to load and invoke arbitrary classes in your namespace.